# Estimation of a sequence related to the Stirling's formula

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that $$n!=\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}e^{\lambda_n}$$
where $$\frac{1}{12(n+1)}<\lambda_n$$

I calculated that $$\lambda_n=\ln n!+n-n\ln n -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi n)$$

On Wikipedia I found that

$$(*)\quad\ln \Gamma (x+1)+x-x\ln x -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi x)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\arctan\left(\frac{t}{x}\right)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}dt=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{(x+1)^\overline{{n}}}$$

where $$c_n=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1x^{\overline{n}}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)dx$$
and $$x^{\overline{n}}=x(x+1)(x+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+n-1)$$
From all this I get $$\lambda_n=\ln n!+n-n\ln n -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2\pi n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{c_k}{(n+1)^{\overline{k}}}>\frac{c_1}{n+1}=\frac{1}{12(n+1)}$$

The only problem I have is that I don't know how to prove (*) equalities which I found on Wikipedia.
 Here's the link to Wikipedia [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

EDIT. I made a mistake because I missed a line over n in formulas. I changes some things because now you can't compute exact formula for $c_n$.

Comment: You should probably link to the Wikipedia pages you found this on to make it easier for potential answerers

Comment: The estimate you want to follows from the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) with $f(x)=1/x$ for $p=1$ (so essentially just one integration by parts).

Comment: I don't see this at all. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: This is the Binet's second formula for $\log(\Gamma(z))$. You can find a proof here https://ia902704.us.archive.org/11/items/courseofmodernan00whit/courseofmodernan00whit_bw.pdf

Comment: @Kulisty 
i gave a proof of this identity uuiet recently here on MSE
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604840/a-log-gamma-identity-where-does-it-come-from/1604938#1604938